# Populate an SQL Server 2k8 with Oracle Loader files

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, migration, sql-loader

Here's the problem:

I have a project that needs to be migrated to Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

We have data in text files for the Oracle SQL Loader and now we need to get that data into the SQL Server DB.

I could write a program that converts everything into INSERT statements but there has to be a more comfortable way to so this.

Any suggestions?

PS: I don't think my company wants to buy additional Software to do this job so that's out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has a bulk loader interface, which you can learn about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

Depending on what format it's in now, you might also consider [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx), which is supposed to be great at such things, and which you may already own with SQL Server 2008.

(I say "supposed to" because in my experience, it is so buggy and quirky that it's usually faster to do it manually. YMMV.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it didn't work out so well. The BULK INSERT is not able to parse our data files correctly. I believe it is possible to teach it how to read the files but I'm faster if I write a script that parses everything into SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.sql-workbench.net/
It has some nice tools for bulk loading data.